# How to specify release/debug build mode when using Android Studio building native app

Tags: android, native

My app calls c++ from java, I found my c++ code is slow compared to the app I generated by using Visual Studio for Mobile Development.

Here's 1 solution I have tried.

(1) 
define CMake build type in app/build.gradle:

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            ...
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me, thanks.

Edit 1

I know how to do, in Android Studio Build-> Select Build Variant, choose release and it will disable debug.